# Having issues with wordpress pagination with multiple categories

Tags: pagination

I’m having issues with my pagination in wordpress. Whenever I navigate to my archive section (news category), pagination works correctly. But, the issue lies with the plugin I’m using to generate a category specific archive. This plugin is dependant on permalink structure being:

/%cateogry%/%year% /%monthnum% /%postname%/

When I click on the link “December 2010” (which is supposed to display a list of posts dated in Dec. 2010 from the “news” category), the plugin passes a url that looks like:

www.my-site.com/news/2010/12/

That url causes the pagination to stop working because the link to page 2 looks like:

www.my-site.com/news/2010/12/page/2/

Is there a way to get this to work regardless of the category name change? I’m using multiple categories

Example:

### Working

News archive: www.my-site.com/news/

Page 2: www.my-site.com/news/page/2/

### NOT Working (after plugin does its thing)

News archive (Dec 12): www.my-site.com/news/2010/12/page/2/

Comment: It would help if you would name and include a link to the plugin you are using. If it is custom post the source code somewhere like http://gist.github.com and update your question to include a link.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll keep that in mind for the future. The plugin I am using to display my category specific archive is called WordPress Category Archive - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-archive/

I did more research and found a plugin that corrects the category pagination issue. The name is Category Pagination fix - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-pagination-fix/

Thank you for trying to help! It is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I did more research and found a plugin that corrects the pagination issues with multiple categories. To summarize, I am using using a plugin called

*WordPress Category Archive* - www.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-archive/

to display my category specific archive. There were some issues with pagination due to the year/month being included in the url.

**The Solution**: A plugin called

*Category Pagination fix* - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-pagination-fix/

Everything is working perfectly now! Hope this helps others. Thanks :)